# 3rd Party passing variable to ASP with session data in URL

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, session-state

I have an ASP form that allows for a database to be searched. The form has a search box (id = street) where people enter their street name and the form will provide a response.

I had a standard HTML form on a bog-standard page on a different website that passed the street variable to the form and the ASP form grabbed this from the URL and this worked fine.

We have since had to update the form to place session data in the URL rather than in a cookie but sadly now the form on the bog-standard page no longer works. The variable does not seam to be recognised by the form.

The format of the sessioned URL is http://www.adomainname.com/(S(mbta4i55vubtxn55gnzhdt55))/form/search.aspx

```
<form action='http://www.adomainname.com/form/search.aspx' method="post"> 
<input type="text" value="High Street" id="street" name="street" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Has anyone had this issue?

Comment: Hi.  What do you mean by the variable does not seem to be recognized by the form?

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're saying...   The action doesn't work because the URL is different?  (Don't shoot me.  I'm just trying to understsand.)  :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear about what you're trying to do yet, but I'll take a shot at the answer...

If you want the street in the URL, change the method to "get".

Comment: Cheers, worked a charm, no idea why it suddenly stopped but all sorted now, thanks